# Reduce javax.net.ssl noise in Wildfly logs

Tags: ssl, logging, wildfly

I'm getting tons of messages like this, all around the SSL protocols that I purposely am not supporting e.g. SSLv3, TLS1.0, etc.

```
2020-02-06 13:08:30,600 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-2) Closing SSLConduit after exception on handshake: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No matching application layer protocol values
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:311)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
```

How can I suppress these in Wildfly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the CLI this should work:

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=io.undertow.request:add(level=FATAL)
```